# jQuery SheepIt: Data injection into "Date" Input Type

Tags: jquery, date, forms, sheepit

**I actually already have an answer for this, but am posting here in case anyone else has the same problem**

Using the SheepIt jQuery plug-in, I cannot inject data into input fields of type date, such as:

```
<input type='date' name='birthday' />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you are formatting the date as YYYY-MM-DD.  Formatting days or months without leading zeros will cause an error, as will using any other delimiter other than `-`.
2. Change your SheepIt plugin file.  Line 1073 needs to include `type == 'date'` in the conditional check, like so:

   ```
   // hidden, text, password
   if (type == 'text' || type == 'hidden' || type == 'password' || type == 'date') {
       field.attr('value', value);
       return true;
   }
   ```